# SSIS error in VS 2019 - The Script Task "XXX" uses version 16.0 script that is not supported in this release of Integration Services

Tags: sql, ssis

This error just started occurring on a few developers' systems across several packages, but I can't track down a specific cause or update.  We have SSIS processes created across various targets (SQL 2012 and up), but when I open them in Visual Studio 2019 this error occurs:

Error loading XXXXXXX.dtsx: There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: System.Exception: The Script Task "ST_36ae893a14204fac97ce8ce3b4ce8ebb" uses version 16.0 script that is not supported in this release of Integration Services. To run the package, use the Script Task to create a new VSTA script. In most cases, scripts are converted automatically to use a supported version, when you open a SQL Server Integration Services package in %SQL_PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME% Integration Services.
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.LoadFromXML(XmlElement elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)

I can open the script task, but it's as if it's new, none of the existing code is there.  Some of the older packages I can open in like Visual Studio 2017 and they work, but in Visual Studio 2019 not so much.  Even some packages built in Visual Studio 2019 are doing this.  Here's my dev environment:

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
Version 16.11.17
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.11.17+32630.194

Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084

SQL Server Data Tools   16.0.62205.05200
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

SQL Server Integration Services   16.0.948.0
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer

I've tried changing the Target server to different versions, but it seems once the issue occurs it resets the script task removing all code.  I'm really confused.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a unique issue as no replies nor can I find any posts about this on other forums.  I've seem similar errors when someone opens an ssis process created in a prior version of SSIS, and updating the target server fixes it -- i've ran into this myself.  But given version 16.0 is SQL 2022 and I'm running this on VS 2019 I wonder if some update has pushed a SQL 2022 resource that is being read by mistake.  I'm not running VS 2022 or SSMS 19, so AFAIK I don't have any SQL 2022 components installed.

Comment: Is anyone experiencing this error now? Does anyone have a solution yet? Been searching for hours now but still can't find a work around for this.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  If I remove ScriptTask and then add it back in, pointing to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Tasks folder (I have to browse to get to this DLL), when I save my code, the reference changes to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\SSIS\160\Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll

Comment: Same here - additionally, when compiled and the dtsx package is exported to SQL Server 2019, it will refuse to have an enabled job.  You can click the enable on the schedule but it always resets itself.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a good answer, but it does seem to fix the issue.  I'm using SQL Server Integration Services 16.0.948.0 (v4.3), but if I go back down to 15.0.2000.180 (v3.16) the issue seems to go away.  So, it's something with version 4.0 and up.  Not ideal to go backwards as we're losing some of the updates - but it gets me going again.  If anyone has other suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2019/01/29/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-there-was-an-exception-while-loading-script-task-from-xml/   The former is Dave's solution.  I've been rewriting the script tasks in Python and integrating them into the package.  Seems to work.  I've always been disappointed in SSIS despite using it for the last 15 years.  Try upgrading to a newer version of SSMS.